# Multiple Checkbox con react hooks

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, checkbox, redux

Muchas Gracias a quien me pueda colaborar. Desde react hooks Intento que multiples checkbox, que al ser seleccionados guarden su valor en la base de datos, pero lo que consigo es que unicamente se guarde el valor del ultimo click que se le dio sin importar si esta seleccionado o no, y cuando lo consulto en la Base de datos, como se puede ver en la imagen, la tarjeta me trae que efectivamente ha guardado el nombre de la Subcategoria (Sopa) pero la categoria solamente ha guardado una de los checkbox (Almuerzo Especial) y el otro checkbox no lo ha guardado (Almuerzo casero), ademas si lo deseleccione de todos modos lo guarda como seleccionado  [image: Imagen de formulario y tarjeta(derecha) que se pinta desde la base de datos]

el codigo es el siguiente

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  borraSubCategoria,
  ingresaSubCategoria,
  listaSubCategorias,
} from "../actions/subCategoriaAction";
import LoadingBox from "../components/LoadingBox";
import MessageBox from "../components/MessageBox";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  BORRA_SUBCATEGORIA_RESET,
  SUBCATEGORIA_REGISTER_RESET,
} from "../constants/categoriaConstants";
import { listaCategoriaGral } from "../actions/categoriaAction";

export default function CreaSubCategoriaScreen(props) {
  const [categoria, setCategoria] = useState("");
  const [nombre, setNombre] = useState("");

  const redirigir = props.location.search
    ? props.location.search.split("=")[1]
    : "/creaSubCategoria";

  const categoriasLista = useSelector((state) => state.categoriasLista);
  const {
    loading: loadingLista,
    error: errorLista,
    categorias,
  } = categoriasLista;

  const subCategoriasLista = useSelector((state) => state.subCategoriasLista);
  const {
    loading: loadingSubLista,
    error: errorSubLista,
    subCategorias,
  } = subCategoriasLista;

  const subCategoriaRegister = useSelector((state) => state.subCategoriaRegister);
  const {
    loading: loadingRegister,
    error: errorRegister,
    successRegister,
  } = subCategoriaRegister;

  const subCategoriaBorra = useSelector((state) => state.subCategoriaBorra);
  const {
    loading: loadingBorra,
    error: errorBorra,
    success: successBorra,
  } = subCategoriaBorra;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(ingresaSubCategoria(categoria, nombre));
    Redirect("/creaSubCategoria");
  };

  const deleteHandler = (subcategoria) => {
    if (window.confirm("¿Está seguro que desea Eliminar?")) {
      dispatch(borraSubCategoria(subcategoria._id));
      Redirect("/creaSubCategoria");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: SUBCATEGORIA_REGISTER_RESET });
    dispatch(listaSubCategorias());
    dispatch(listaCategoriaGral());
    if (successRegister) {
      props.history.push(redirigir);
    }
    if (successBorra) {
      dispatch({ type: BORRA_SUBCATEGORIA_RESET });
      props.history.push(redirigir);
    }
  }, [dispatch, props.history, redirigir, successRegister, successBorra]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="espacio"></div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
          <div className="card mb-4 orangeclaro">
            <div className="card-header">
              <h3 className="text-center">Crear SubCategoria</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
              <form className="form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="nombre">
                    Nombre de SubCategoria
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="nombre"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Ingrese Nombre Categoria"
                    required
                    onChange={(e) => setNombre(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="categoria">
                    Categorias pertenece
                  </label>
                  <div className="input-group">
                    {categorias === 0 && <option>No hay Catagorias</option>}
                    {loadingLista ? (
                      <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
                    ) : errorLista ? (
                      <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorLista}</MessageBox>
                    ) : (
                      categorias.map((categoria) => (
                        <div className="form-group m-2 p-2 border">
                          <label className="mr-2" htmlFor="categoria">
                            {categoria.nombre}
                          </label>
                          <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            id="categoria"
                            value={categoria.nombre}
                            onChange={(e) => setCategoria(e.target.value)}
                          />
                        </div>
                      ))
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>

                <button className="btn btn-danger btn-block mt-4">Crear</button>
              </form>
              {loadingBorra && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
              {errorBorra && (
                <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorBorra}</MessageBox>
              )}
              {loadingRegister && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
              {successRegister && (
                <MessageBox variant="primary">
                  <h6> SUBCATEGORIA CREADA CORRECTAMENTE</h6>
                </MessageBox>
              )}
              {errorRegister && (
                <MessageBox variant="danger">
                  <h6> ERROR AL INGRESAR SUBCATEGORIA</h6>
                  <p>
                    Revise que no esté repetido el nombre,algún dato errado o
                    comuniquese con el Administrador{" "}
                  </p>
                  <p>{errorRegister}</p>
                </MessageBox>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            {loadingSubLista ? (
              <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
            ) : errorSubLista ? (
              <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorSubLista}</MessageBox>
            ) : (
              <>
                <div className="container mx-auto ">
                  {subCategorias.length === 0 && (
                    <MessageBox>
                      <h5 className="text-center">No Existen Categorias </h5>
                    </MessageBox>
                  )}
                </div>
                <div className="row center">
                  {subCategorias.map((subcategoria) => (
                    <div
                      className="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"
                      key={categoria._id}
                    >
                      <div className="card orangeclaro">
                        <div className="card-header text-center">                          
                          <p>
                            <h5 className="card-title">{subcategoria.nombre}</h5>
                          </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-body mx-auto">
                          <p>Categoria: {subcategoria.categoria}</p>
                            <div>
                              <button
                                type="button"
                                className="small btn btn-danger btn-block"
                                onClick={() => deleteHandler(subcategoria)}
                              >
                                Borrar
                              </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Para acercarlos mas al codigo aqui discrimino parte del codigo y la duda la tengo y es cuando traigo los checkbox desde la Base de Datos que en este caso son cuatro, pero podrian ser o más o menos

```js
<div className="input-group">
                    {categorias === 0 && <option>No hay Catagorias</option>}
                    {loadingLista ? (
                      <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
                    ) : errorLista ? (
                      <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorLista}</MessageBox>
                    ) : (
                      categorias.map((categoria) => (
                        <div className="form-group m-2 p-2 border">
                          <label className="mr-2" htmlFor="categoria">
                            {categoria.nombre}
                          </label>
                          <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            id="categoria"
                            value={categoria.nombre}
                            onChange={(e) => setCategoria(e.target.value)}
                          />
                        </div>
                      ))
                    )}
                  </div>
```